# Why don't certain GNOME apps show in Slingshot?

Tags: slingshot, apps, nautilus, gnome

I would like to replace Pantheon Files with Nautilus in Freya 0.3.1. However, this doesn't work properly. After installing Nautilus it does not show in Slingshot. Nor can I add it to the dock because there is no symbol.

I then removed Pantheon Files because I thought both programs might be interfering. But to no avail.

It is possible to start Nautilus from Terminal. But then the following lines show up in Terminal:

```
$ nautilus
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "pantheon-filechooser-module"
nautilus-wipe-Message: Initializing
```

I am using an old MacBook 13" Core2Duo, Early 2008. In other respects, Freya is working just fine.

Comment: Are you aware that Nautilus will (most likely) simply be called "Files" in Slingshot? (So it has the same name as Pantheon Files, which is not a problem except for the user confusing both.)

Comment: Yes. But Nautilus does not show even after I uninstalled Pantheon Files. I can start it via Terminal, but it does not show in Slingshot

Comment: Thiago Jedi's solution worked - now I have two "Files" apps in Slingshot. One is Pantheon Files, the other Nautilus. So you're both right :) Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `.desktop` file for nautilus by default shows only when the desktop environment is Unity or Gnome.

To show Nautilus on slingshot you'll need to edit the desktop entry.

Edit the file `/usr/share/applications/nautilus.desktop` with this command:

```
sudo -H scratch-text-editor /usr/share/applications/nautilus.desktop
```

And then change the line `OnlyShowIn=GNOME;Unity;` to `OnlyShowIn=GNOME;Unity;Pantheon;`.

It should now appear in slingshot and you'll be able to add to plank too with the same method.