# How to add desktop shortcuts for installed applications - freya?

Tags: release-freya, applications, desktop

I tried to add my custom shortcuts for my installed apps.  But I can't found a right tutorial to do this operations.

Can anyone suggest me to create a desktop shortcut for my custom apps?

I have not find a solution for my question by reading the article.

Comment: You want  to create shortcuts ON desktop or in applications menu?

Comment: @Ravan -please understand the  question is not duplicate. adding shortcut is different from enabling shortcuts.And all other bee followed persons who mark it as duplicate. remove the duplicate mark

Comment: I stated Desktop Shortcuts in my question itself

Comment: You are correct, then this will be closed as "unclear"(for me atleast). The linked dup do the job of creating desktop shortcut. Which is same in your accepted answer except wording.

Comment: What they answered is for older version of elementary,  and also that's not answered my question/.

Comment: Well, are you able to launch the app, for which you want to create shortcut, from application menu?

Comment: Not Applications menu. Let me say from my own view. I  installed Tweak tools. but i cant find its shortcut on applications menu. Whenever i  need to  open this tool, i have to got '/usr/share/application/'  and i open it.  So i want to create a shortcut for this tool. ?

Comment: then your question is duplicate of [this](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/2994/why-dont-certain-gnome-apps-show-in-slingshot) one.

Comment: I have no idea, what are you trying to pull from this question.  but i can say one thing.  my question is not similar, and what he(shrestha-aj) answered is not wrong. so if you wish to mark it as duplicate. go a head.  but i got solution from his answer.Not from any of these questions.  . Thank you for your patience to mark it as duplicate,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, the desktop in elementary freya is disabled. You need to enable it first. After enabling the desktop, open the file browser and navigate to:
   /usr/share/applications/

You can find list of installed applications there. Select the applications you want, **copy** it and paste it in the desktop.

Comment: How can I enable desktop?

Comment: To enable desktop in Elementary Freya, check this tutorial: http://mylinuxideas.blogspot.it/2015/04/enable-desktop-icons-and-right-click-on.html

Comment: the tutorial has same content as the linked duplicate.

Comment: @Ravan My question is not enabling the desktop icons. I want to create shortcuts for my installed apps.

Comment: @shrestha_aj What you said is easy way to add shortcuts.

Comment: @Kvvaradha what I have [asked](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/3767/how-to-add-desktop-shortcuts-for-installed-applications-freya/3769?noredirect=1#comment6439_3767)?

Comment: @Ravan-got my point?

Comment: @Kvvaradha Happy to help :)

Comment: Happy New Year everyone! Cheers!!

Answer (score 2):

Create a "name.desktop" file in "/usr/share/applications/"

> [Desktop Entry]
>
> Name= (the name)
>
> GenericName= (the name)
>
> Exec= (the command)
>
> Icon= (the icon path)
>
> Terminal=false
>
> Type=Application
>
> StartupNotify=true