# FontViewer v3.20.2 missing icon from "Applications" menu

Tags: applications, icons, fonts

elementary OS 0.4 Loki
AppCenter shows FontViewer v3.20.2 as installed.

However, there is no icon available under "Applications"

Although can be searched and launched; was wondering if there is a appropriate way to add the missing icon to appropriate / intuitive location for example under "System Settings"

Answer (score 1):

I recommend Menulibre
https://smdavis.us/projects/menulibre/
It's simple GUI to add applications to slingshot and/or change names, icons etc.

However, if you want to keep simple. Make a .desktop entry in /usr/share/applications.
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Desktop_entries

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution for Nautilus, but it's the same for any other app:
[Why don't certain GNOME apps show in Slingshot?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/2994/why-dont-certain-gnome-apps-show-in-slingshot)